# Initializing ungiven constructor arguments, how?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to add an additional argument into a constructor:

e.g. adding the argument 'y'

```
public Object(int x, int y) {
  int x1;
  int y1;
  x1=x;
  y1=y;
}
```

the original constructor was

```
public Object(int x) {
  int x1;
  int y1;
  x1=x;
  y1=(default number);
}
```

---

I know in Java, you could do something like `this(x, 1)` to set `y` to 1 if y is not given, but I think I read that constructors calling constructors doesn't work in C++?

Is there a way to initialize `y` when it's not given, i.e. making sure that *(1)* and *(2)* both work?

```
Object o1 = new Object (5);   // (1)
Object o2 = new Object (5,3); // (2)
```

Comment: Instead of trying to show us what you mean with syntax that doesn't exist (and is therefore meaningless), perhaps _explain_ your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sup>**Note**: 
>   For starters you are confusing the syntax of *java* with that off *C++*, what you have in your post is not valid C++. In either case; what you are looking can be solved using *default arguments*, or *constructor delegation** (c++11).</sup>

---

**ALTERNATIVE #1: DEFAULT ARGUMENTS**

Adding a *default argument* to a function declaration will make it possible to call the function, in this case a constructor, without specifying a value.

---

```
#include <iostream>
```

```
class Obj {
  public:
    Obj (int x, int y = 123) {
       std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << std::endl;
    }

    ...
};
```

```
Obj a (1);
Obj b (2, 3);
```

---

Output

```
x: 1, y: 123
x: 2, y: 3
```

---

---

**ALTERNATIVE #2: CONSTRUCTOR DELEGATION**

In *C++11* you can call another constructor from one constructor using the *mem-initializer*, as in the below example. The output will be identical to the example using *default arguments*.

```
class Obj {
  public:
     Obj (int x, int y) { // (1)
       std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << std::endl;
     }

     Obj (int x)
       : Obj (x, 123)     // call (1)
     { }
};
```

```
Obj a (1);
Obj b (2, 3);
```